# Integration JSF, Spring and Primefaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I'm new at Java and i'm studying some technologies, and i want to know if its possible to integrate JSF, Spring and Primefaces. I'm searching for some tips but i only found JSF + Spring or Spring + Primefaces or Spring + JSF or JSF + Primefaces but never all 3 together.
It's possible to integrate all of them ?

Att,

Pedro Henrique

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Note that PrimeFaces is simply a component library that works on top of the JSF specification (just an additional JAR in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory), so it's more or less understood that if you can integrate something with JSF (Spring, in this case), you can use PrimeFaces alongside with it.

That may not always be true (for example, if you use some Javascript library that may conflict with what PrimeFaces uses), but nowadays it usually is.

Comment: Thanks, you opened the ways for me. Really thanks!